# Is there any difference between e2fsck and e4fsck on CentOS / RHEL systems?

Tags: centos, rhel, ext4, fsck

ext4.wiki.kernel.org makes it sound like [e2fsck was simply renamed to e4fsck](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Howto#For_people_who_are_running_RHEL.2FCentOS) so that e4fsprogs and e2fsprogs could coexist without overlapping. However, there is no mention of any difference in the code of the command.

The [e2fsck man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/e2fsck) makes no mention of ext4, but does mention that it works with ext3 (i.e. ext2 with journaling turned on).

For Ubuntu, [apparently e2fsck can handle ext2, 3 ***and*** 4 filesystems.](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man8/fsck.ext2.8.html)

And of course there's good ol' vanilla [fsck](http://linux.die.net/man/8/fsck) which itself makes no mention of ext4.

If I need to fsck an ext4 file system on a RHEL based system, which tool do I use? e4fsck? But if it's just a rename of e2fsck, can I just use that instead? Why does Ubuntu mention ext4 in its e2fsck man page but no one else seems to? And what about plain fsck on ext4?

**EDIT:**

On a Fedora 14 machine there is fsck.ext4, fsck.ext3 and fsck.ext2 in /sbin/. They all have the exact same file size. Curioser and Curioser.

**EDIT 2:**

Furthermore, when running fsck.ext4, you see that it appears to be e2fsck running. For example, I see this line when running fsck.ext4: `e2fsck: aborted` Tricksters!

Comment: Aaaaa! Who let the Choptars in here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`e4fsprogs` on RHEL5 is just a newer version of `e2fsprogs`.  Red Hat has a policy of not upgrading to newer, binary-incompatible versions of things, so they "had to" stay on the old `e2fsprogs` they were using, and the solution they came up with to support `ext4` was to introduce the newer version as `e4fsprog`s (with s/2/4/ on all of the command names).  To make matters worse, `ext4` support on RHEL 5 is technically a "technology preview".

I understand why they did it, but it is annoying, since you won't find `e4fs*` on any other distribution, *including* RHEL 6.

Comment: Thanks Steven! Is the situation any clearer in RHEL / CentOS 6? Furthermore, it seems like this is not the normal behavior on most other distributions. e4fsck and fsck.ext4 seem to be RHEL-only anomalies. Am I to take it that updated versions of fsck can handle ext4 just fine?

Comment: By "any other distribution", I meant including newer RHEL, so I edited that into my answer.  And yes, newer e2fsprogs handle ext2, ext3, and ext4 equally well.

Comment: `/sbin/fsck.*` are there to make `fsck -t` work.  That's totally normal.  The various `fsck.ext*` are hard links to `e2fsck`, which is why they appear to have the same size and such.  They're actually different names for the same file.  Well, except on RHEL 5, where `/sbin/fsck.ext4` is a hard link to `/sbin/e4fsck` instead.

Comment: ... and e4fsck is just e2fsck which is just fsck. Totally get it now. =)

Comment: ext4 was Tech Preview from RHEL 5.3 to 5.5, but in 5.6+ it's fully supported.